# Using the apps-script-oauth2 lib - how to execute callback after authorization?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using the [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) lib in my google app script project. Works fine so far. I need you advice on this. Cant wrap my head arount it. How do I use the lib so that is executes a callback with set parameters right after the authorization process is finished by the user?

With `.setCallbackFunction('authCallback')` you can set up a callback that will be executed, however, I cant hand it parameters AND my callback will be different each time ("since i wanna do different requests to the api right after the authorization).

Comment: Did you read your [link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/README.md#passing-additional-parameters-to-the-callback-function)?

Comment: Of course I read it.

Comment: Why? I tried several approaches, but I don’t consider them with posting here since they may mislead.

Comment: Did you read the part titled ``Passing additional parameters to the callback function``? If you have a specific issue implementing that, You should provide [mcve]

Comment: Yes, but a whole callback function?